What is the cardinality of the Diffeomorphism group $\text{Diff}(\mathbb{R})$ over the reals?
As a small set-up, we have $\aleph_0$ as the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$, and then the cardinality of the reals $\mathbb{R}$ is $\beth_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$. In particular, it turns out that this is also the cardinality of the power set of the natural numbers $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and the cardinality of the set of permutations $\Pi(\mathbb{N})$. In general, the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ of an infinite set $A$ and the set of permutations $\Pi(A)$ indeed seem to have the same cardinality.
So $\Pi(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ likewise have the same cardinality, in this case it is $\beth_2 = 2^{\beth_1}$. Now I wonder if the cardinality of $\text{Diff}(\mathbb{R})$ is also $\beth_2$? But $\text{Diff}(\mathbb{R})$ seems like it should be smaller than $\Pi(\mathbb{R})$ ... do you know more?

@SassatelliGiulio you're right! That does answer my question, thank you :)
